# Font export from Inkscape problem

Tags: inkscape

Why is font-size, font-color and font-type missing in the resulting image.pdf_tex? I use Inkscape on Ubuntu and save as pdf with PDF+LaTex option.
This message appear in the image.pdf_tex file:

```
\errmessage{(Inkscape) Color is used for the text in Inkscape, but the package 'color.sty' is not loaded}%
```

This is also in the image.pdf_tex file:

```
\put(0.11060533,0.4582626){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{A small black text in Liberation Sans}}}%
    \put(0,0.36561993){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{A bigger black text in Lib. Mono}}}%
    \put(0.53732692,0.27297743){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{A small red text in Liberation Sans}}}
```

In Inkscape, the three texts are visible as they are described.

Comment: Load the package `\usepackage{color}`.

Comment: In Inkscape? As I understand it, the image.pdf_tex has not yet passed through LaTex.

Comment: Did you tried the [`inkscape2tikz`](https://code.google.com/p/inkscape2tikz/) script? Never used since I code my figures directly but maybe it’s an alternative to you …

Comment: Are there any news here?